# Can assigning smaller integer type to a larger integer type be unsafe?

Tags: c++

Apart from the case where smaller type is signed and is < 0 and larger is unsigned, are there any other cases where assigning smaller int type to a larger int type can be unsafe?

Comment: Are you looking for something specific?

Answer (score 1):

I think No. Because the larger type can accomodate all the bit information of the smaller type. The only problem could be the signed/unsigned things (as its always the case when mixing signed with unsigned). But then you can get back the original value anytime. No loss of information.

```
signed short s = -1;
unsigned int i = s;
signed short originalValue = (signed short)i;

cout << s << endl;
cout << i << endl;
cout << originalValue  << endl;
```

Output:

```
-1
4294967295
-1
```

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/z3G9x

Comment: Technically, the conversion back to signed is implementation-defined if the value is out-of-range.

Comment: @Oli: Really? Can you please give me the reference?

Comment: @Oli: Out-of-range for the smaller type? If so, then it doesn't apply to the case I've asnwered, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: I can give you a C99 reference: 6.3.1.3, paragraph3.  I'm sure something similar exists in the C++ standard; I will check.

Comment: @Nawaz: The value `4294967295` cannot be represented by a `signed short`.

Comment: @Nawaz: In the 2005 draft, at least, see section 4.7 paragraph 3.

Comment: @Oli: What if I write `(signed short)(signed int)i;`, then?

Comment: @Nawaz: Still undefined, technically.  In practice, these methods will work absolutely fine on most platforms.

Comment: @Nawaz: `4294967295` is not representable by a `signed int`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no problem assigning smaller integer types to larget integer types.

The problem is the other way around.